# Не могу в свою модель данных вогнать Json

Tags: java, android, gson

Вот json в котором каждый раз появляются новые пары ключ-значение, их то больше , то меньше.  Я хочу добавить каждую пару в отдельную ModelData(String, Double).

Вот до чего дошел : `Type type = new TypeToken<ModelData>(){}.getType();`

Далее `ModelData myData = GSON.fromJson()` но что подать на вход. Он хочет JsonReader и type.  А JsonReader в свою очередь требует Reader. Как сделать Reader , если имеется только json объект.

И на правильном ли я вообще пути?

У меня подключена библиотека json-simple и GSON

Попробовал такое

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ModelData>(){}.getType();
        ModelData myData = GSON.fromJson(json,type);
```

но не получаю чего то похожего на то, что получается , если использовать вместо ModelDate  Map <'String, Double>.

```
 {
"base": "EUR",
"date": "2017-12-06",
"rates": {
    "AUD": 1.5565,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "BRL": 3.8193,
    "CAD": 1.4963,
    "CHF": 1.1678,
    "CNY": 7.8169,
    "CZK": 25.636,
    "DKK": 7.4421,
    "GBP": 0.88335,
    "HKD": 9.2323,
    "HRK": 7.5463,
    "HUF": 314.45,
    "IDR": 16007,
    "ILS": 4.1519,
    "INR": 76.243,
    "JPY": 132.52,
    "KRW": 1291.5,
    "MXN": 22.203,
    "MYR": 4.816,
    "NOK": 9.7575,
    "NZD": 1.7141,
    "PHP": 59.891,
    "PLN": 4.2142,
    "RON": 4.632,
    "RUB": 69.791,
    "SEK": 9.9265,
    "SGD": 1.5925,
    "THB": 38.559,
    "TRY": 4.5489,
    "USD": 1.1817,
    "ZAR": 15.985
}
}
```

.Тут я получаю rates который хочу в массив ModelData.

```
    Object obj = new Object();
    try {
        // Считываем json
        obj = new JSONParser().parse(answer);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;
    String Currency = (String) jo.get("base");
    String Date = (String) jo.get("date");
    JSONObject rates = (JSONObject) jo.get("rates");

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(ModelData.class,new DeserializerCurrency())
            .create();

    ModelData modelData = gson.fromJson(rates.toJSONString(),ModelData.class);
```

.

```
    class ModelData {

    private String name;
    private Double value;


    ModelData(String name, Double value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    Double getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

.

```
public class DeserializerCurrency implements JsonDeserializer<ModelData> {

@Override
public ModelData deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    System.out.println("ДЕсериализатор");
    ModelData modelData = null;
    if(json.isJsonObject()){
        Set<Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>> entrySet = json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
        System.out.println("Размер" +  entrySet.size());
        if(entrySet.size() > 0){
            Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry = entrySet.iterator().next();
            modelData = new ModelData(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue().getAsDouble());
            }
        }
        return modelData;
    }
}
```

и пробую парсить, я понимаю в десериализаторе надо поставить цикл и записывать в массив. Что то доделать не могу   : 
`

```
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(ModelData.class,new DeserializerCurrency())
                .create();

        ModelData modelData = gson.fromJson(rates.toJSONString(),ModelData.class);`
```

**UPD**

Я переделал десериализатор.

```
 public class DeserializerCurrency implements JsonDeserializer<ModelData> {

    @Override
    public ModelData deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        ModelData modelData = null;
        List<ModelData> ListModelData = new ArrayList<>();
        if(json.isJsonObject()){
            Set<Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>> entrySet = json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
            if(entrySet.size() > 0){
                Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>> entries = entrySet.iterator();
              while (entries.hasNext()){
                  Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry = entries.next();
                  ListModelData.add(new ModelData(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue().getAsDouble()));
              }
            }
        }

        return modelData;
    }
}
```

Теперь в массиве всё что надо, но вернуть его не могу, так как в return один объект, а не массив. Для этого надо подключить другой интерфейс, типо JsonDeserializer> . Как быть? Класс такого типа я создать не могу, что на вход подать то?

Comment: Так а чем не устраивает `Map <String, Double>`?

Comment: Покажите ваш класс `ModelData`

Comment: eugeneek , тем что читал где то что работа в listView с ним проблемна  и тем что у меня код уже завязан на ModelData и хотелось бы поэксперементировать с своей моделью данных. Модель данных сейчас добавлю к вопросу

Comment: Barmaley, хотел добавить каждую пару ключ значение в ArrayList<ModelData>

Comment: Да, я понял... Я бы не стал это делать средствами GSon - я тупо парсил бы каждую строчку низкоуровневым парсером и пихал уже в `ArrayList<>`

Comment: Приложу сейчас к вопросу , то что сделал. Не пойму как получить массив ModelData , а не только первое значение

Comment: уточните, вы получаете именно такой json? К чему относится rates? Может покажите источник, откуда получаете, если он общедоступный.

Comment: Сейчас приложу полный ответ

Comment: и вам нужно вытащить только rates, остальные данный можно потерять?

Comment: Виктор,Ну как видите остальные я вытаскиваю по названию строк. А эти по названиям вытащить не могу так как динамический этот список, там новые пары появляются в зависимости от запроса.  Я бы хотел еще и массив с ключами получить, отдельный массив  с значениями и массив ModelDate.

Comment: @Turalllb нет я спрашивал, нужны ли вам значения base и date?

Comment: Нужны. Вы про то что будет красиво, если их тоже добавить в десериализатор ? я просто не знаю как мне оттуда их возвращать. Я хочу в десериализаторе еще и массив из ключей  . И получается мне нужно два массива как то забрать оттуда .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### С помощью `Map<String, Double>`

*Модель:*

```
public class ModelData {
    Map<String, Double> rates = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ModelData{" +
                "rates=" + rates +
                '}';
    }
}
```

*Маин:*

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ModelData modelData = gson.fromJson(JSON2, ModelData.class);
```

---

Если вам не нужна `Map`, а нужна каждая валюта по отдельности, то это можно сделать 1000 и 1 различными способами.

*Моя импровизация:*

```
public class ModelData {
    Map<String, Double> rates = new HashMap<>();

    public List<Currency> convertToCurrency(){
        return rates.entrySet().stream()
                .map(m -> new Currency(m.getKey(), m.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static class Currency{
        String name;
        double val;

        public Currency(String name, double val) {
            this.name = name;
            this.val = val;
        }
    }

}
```

Теперь если в маин вызвать метод, получить список валют и вывести на экран получим:

```
Currency{name='AUD', val=1.5565}
Currency{name='BGN', val=1.9558}
Currency{name='BRL', val=3.8193}
Currency{name='CAD', val=1.4963}
...
```

Так же можно просто в `ModelData` определить метод, в который передавать имя валюты, а возвращать объект Currency. Либо напрямую с `Map` общаться...

---

Я с JSON знаком, но не могу объяснить в чем конкретно ваша ошибка и как вам надо сделать в идеале. Надеюсь попозже кто-то объяснит, я пока предложил вам рабочий вариант.

---

### Вариант 2: распарсить все ручками (частный случай):

Т.к. автору нужны все данные, а не только валюты, нужна модель входящих данных:

```
class IncomeData {
    // без конструкторов, toString и гет\сет для экономии места
    String base;
    LocalDate date;
    List<ModelData> rates;
}
```

`ModelData` не изменилась (имя, значение).

Вся работа со строкой, во входящей строке лежит `json` из вопроса (полный).

```
public IncomeData deserialize(String json) throws JSONException {
    //парсим строку в json
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    //забираем base и date
    String base = jsonObject.get("base").toString();
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(jsonObject.get("date").toString());

    //заберем объект rates и пройдемся по нему итератором
    //все валюты сложим в свои ModelData и все сложим в лист
    JSONObject rates = jsonObject.getJSONObject("rates");
    Iterator keys = rates.keys();
    List<ModelData> ratesList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (keys.hasNext()){
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        //Number потому, что по ключу "IDR" прилетает Integer
        Number value = (Number) rates.get(key);
        ratesList.add(new ModelData(key, value.doubleValue()));
    }

    //собираем IncomeData из полученных данных
    IncomeData resultData = new IncomeData(base, date, ratesList);
    return resultData;
}
```

В этот метод подаем строку `json` и на выходе получаем готовый объект

Comment: Map это хорошо, но я весь код построил так чтобы избежать работы с map и ListView.  Получить Map можно Type type = new TypeTokenMap<String,Double>(){}.getType();
 Map<String, Double> myData = GSON.fromJson(json,type); и никакой десериализатор и модели не нужны. А я пытаюсь получить Model(String,Double). Десериализатор возвращает всего один первый объект, а я пробую  Массив (Model(String,Double))

Comment: @Turalllb сейчас ещё посидел попытался, что придумать, но все больше склоняюсь к предложению Barmaley. Просто написать свой десериализатор, строчка за строчкой перебрать JSON и вернуть что нужно.

Comment: Виктор, так я всё время этим и занимаюсь, что пытаюсь из десериализатора получить не один объект , как он мне выдавал, а массив. Код десериализатора я изменил и приложил внизу, а как к нему правильно интерфейс подключить не пойму

Comment: @Turalllb дополнил ответ, у меня все отлично отработало попробуйте

Comment: Виктор, да я уже всё это проделал, только не знал как вернуть несколько результатов, значит нужно для этого отдельный класс создавать. А ведь можно еще и callback  ?

Comment: @Turalllb если вам надо вернуть несколько результатов, возвращайте лист или массив. Не совсем понимаю зачем тут callback

Comment: А я просто не заметил, что вы не использовали интерфейс JsonDeserializer. А зачем тогда нужен этот интерфейс, если можно без него десериализатор писать ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69867/discussion-between--and-turalllb).

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен правильно ли я Вас понял, но если вам приходит ответ в JSON формате и надо его распарсить, можно создать класс модель схожую на ответ и сделать следующее:

```
List<User> resList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strJSON)) { // <--- strJSON - Входящий JSON
        return resList;
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    User users = gson.fromJson(strJSON, User.class);
    resList.addAll(Arrays.asList(users));
return resList;
```

Вместо User Ваш класс.

Comment: и буду я получать Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $,   так как в strJSON у меня нет массива , а есть объект с элементами

Comment: ну так уберите скобки массива, в примере я исправил